# React-native-paper dependency not importing in codesandbox

Tags: react-native, codesandbox

I'm following a tutorial from linkedin and the issue seems to be that I haven't understood dependencies exactly right. this line makes it cranky:

```
import {Button} from 'react-native-paper';
```

this is my package file:

```
    {
  "name": "fixmypaper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.*",
    "react-dom": "17.0.*",
    "react-native-paper": "4.11.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

So I added it to the dependencies, do I also need to do something custom with the scripts section of my package?

The exact error is

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Left')

while highlighting the above (button importing) line, which then causes my app.js to not compile. *Note: If I bring in the button from react-native-web, it doesn't crash, so it is something that is a problem with the paper module.*

For the moment my sandbox is public, literally just following a tutorial:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fixmypaper-xx46b?file=/package.json:0-528

I like the idea of developing here while I learn (on codesandbox) and was able to get a subscription, it seems tidier than keeping installations on both of my dev machines that aren't web accessible.

Answer (score 0):

When I clicked your link in the index.js you were importing
`import App from "./App";` when really you should import `import App from "./components/App"`. Since your app.js is in the components folder.
After I made that changed the codesandbox worked.

Comment: I'm still getting an enormous error off to the side. do you see a series of buttons? maybe I need to do something other than just f5 to refresh my view

Comment: I don't know what to tell you it works on my computer after I made that change

Comment: You can try expo-snack too it's similar too codesnadbox. (https://snack.expo.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed React-Native-Paper button to default React-Native button component in Codesandbox.io